# Using multiple filters re-renders component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use filters in an application which limit the output of a list of users. See the example of the same concept in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/q9y2k9vo56)

The idea is that the list accepts multiple filter values to narrow down the search as much as needed. The first filter works fine when typing in any characters, but switching over and then also typing something inside the second filter input rerenders the list and overwrites the search findings of the first filter.

Main Component:

```
  <div className="App">
    <Filters onChange={this.handleFilter} />
    <div className="list">
      <List users={filteredUsers} />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Filter Inputs:

```
<div className="filters">
  <input
    name="name"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Search by name"
    onChange={props.onChange}
  />
  <input
    name="email"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Search by email"
    onChange={props.onChange}
  />
</div>
```

filter handler:

```
  handleFilter = event => {
    const target = event.target;
    let updateUsers = this.state.users;
    updateUsers = updateUsers.filter(user => {
      let type;
      if (target.name === "name") {
        type = user.name;
      } else if (target.name === "email") {
        type = user.email;
      }
      return type.toLowerCase().search(target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
    this.setState({ filteredUsers: updateUsers });
  };
```

I do plan on using several more filters and the list should not re-render.
What is a way to prevent this or work out a better solution?
How to big websites apply their filters?

Comment: If you save the state of each input, you can run your search function for either of the input values rather than one at a time like you currently have.

Comment: can you elaborate? Currently the state is saved via the onChange method

Answer (score 0):

You could set filter values of email and name both to state, then trigger a filter function that uses both of those values for the final result. You should also store the values of filter in state, either that of component or a parent. This way you shouldn't have your search values overwritten.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const Filters = ({ onChange, emailFilterValue, nameFilterValue }) => (
  <div className="filters">
    <input
      name="name"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search by name"
      onChange={onChange}
      value={nameFilterValue}
    />
    <input
      name="email"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search by email"
      onChange={onChange}
      value={emailFilterValue}
    />
  </div>
);

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      nameFilter: "",
      emailFilter: ""
    };
  }

  handleFilter = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    if (name === "email") {
      this.setState({ emailFilter: value });
    } else if (name === "name") {
      this.setState({ nameFilter: value });
    }
    this.filterUsers();
  };

  filterUsers = () => {
    const { users, nameFilter, emailFilter } = this.state;
    let updateUsers = users.slice();
    if (nameFilter.length > "") {
      // do your search based on name
    }
    if (emailFilter.length > "") {
      // then apply email filter
    }
    this.setState({ users: updateUsers });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Filters
          onChange={this.handleFilter}
          emailFilterValue={this.state.emailFilter}
          nameFilterValue={this.state.nameFilter}
        />
        <div className="list">
          <List users={filteredUsers} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of [my solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/50mnv0rkkx). Generally "big websites" reduce the amount of time filtering as much as possible if it's unnecessary. I would equally add a setTimeout() to not filter on EVERY input immediately, and clear said timeout if the user types within 400ms (for example).

In your filter component I would keep track of the filtered words:

```
class Filters extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      name: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    let key = "email";
    if (event.target.name === "name") {
      key = "name";
    }

    this.setState({ [key]: event.target.value });

    onChange({ email: this.state.email, name: this.state.name });
  };

  render() {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="filters">
        <input
          name="name"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search by name"
          onInput={this.handleChange}
        />
        <input
          name="email"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search by email"
          onInput={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And in your App component I would create two different filters, this way it puts a priority on your "name" property if it's filled out:

```
handleFilter = data => {
    let updateUsers = this.state.users;
    console.log(data);

    if (data.name.length > 0) {
      updateUsers = updateUsers.filter(user => {
        return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(data.name);
      });
    }

    if (data.email.length > 0) {
      updateUsers = updateUsers.filter(user => {
        return user.email.toLowerCase().includes(data.email);
      });
    }

    this.setState({ filteredUsers: updateUsers });
  };
```